# tar typeflag directory or file when tar'ing directories in golang

Tags: go

I'm not sure how to set Header.Typeflag when tar'ing a directory with files and subdirectories.  I know if I add

```
header.Typeflag = '0'
```

It will only tar files but not directories.  How do I set the Typeflag when it is a file or directory so when untar'ing I can pass it in a case statement to tar.TypeDir

Example taken from https://www.socketloop.com/tutorials/golang-archive-directory-with-tar-and-gzip

```
package main

 import (
         "archive/tar"
         "compress/gzip"
         "flag"
         "fmt"
         "io"
         "os"
         "strings"
         "path/filepath"
 )

 func checkerror(err error) {

         if err != nil {
                 fmt.Println(err)
                 os.Exit(1)
         }
 }

 func main() {

         flag.Parse() // get the arguments from command line

         destinationfile := flag.Arg(0)

         if destinationfile == "" {
                 fmt.Println("Usage : gotar destinationfile.tar.gz source")
                 os.Exit(1)
         }

         sourcedir := flag.Arg(1)

         if sourcedir == "" {
                 fmt.Println("Usage : gotar destinationfile.tar.gz source-directory")
                 os.Exit(1)
         }

         dir, err := os.Open(sourcedir)

         checkerror(err)

         defer dir.Close()

         files, err := dir.Readdir(0) // grab the files list

         checkerror(err)

         tarfile, err := os.Create(destinationfile)

         checkerror(err)

         defer tarfile.Close()
         var fileWriter io.WriteCloser = tarfile

         if strings.HasSuffix(destinationfile, ".gz") {
                 fileWriter = gzip.NewWriter(tarfile) // add a gzip filter
                 defer fileWriter.Close()            // if user add .gz in the destination filename
         }

         tarfileWriter := tar.NewWriter(fileWriter)
         defer tarfileWriter.Close()

         for _, fileInfo := range files {

                 if fileInfo.IsDir() {
                    continue
                 }

                 // see https://www.socketloop.com/tutorials/go-file-path-independent-of-operating-system

                 file, err := os.Open(dir.Name() + string(filepath.Separator) + fileInfo.Name())

                 checkerror(err)

                 defer file.Close()


                 // prepare the tar header

                 header := new(tar.Header)
                 header.Name = file.Name()
                 header.Size = fileInfo.Size()
                 header.Mode = int64(fileInfo.Mode())
                 header.ModTime = fileInfo.ModTime()


                 err = tarfileWriter.WriteHeader(header)

                 checkerror(err)

                 _, err = io.Copy(tarfileWriter, file)

                 checkerror(err)
         }

 }
```

Comment: Of course instead of `header.Typeflag = '0'` or `header.Typeflag = '5'` you should use `header.Typeflag = tar.TypeReg` and `header.Typeflag = tar.TypeDir` (and only if you want/need something different than what [`tar.FileInfoHeader`](https://golang.org/pkg/archive/tar/#FileInfoHeader) will do for you).

Answer (score 1):

If the files are on disk, which it looks like they are, then that part is done for you.  Have a look at [FileInfoHeader](https://golang.org/src/archive/tar/common.go?s=1401:2114#L198).  That will set the Typeflag based on what it can extrapolate from the resource (directory or file in your case.)

For a complete list of the available options see [the tar standard docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Standard.html)

Comment: I am aware of that, I'm not sure how to set it during tar'ing files if I am passing 0 for file or 5 for directory.

Comment: @Tim, I believe sberry is saying you shouldn't be building the `tar.Header` from scratch (i.e. don't use `header := new(tar.Header)`) but start with `header, err := tar.FileInfoHeader(fileInfo, name)` (where name is something like your `path.Join(dir.Name(), fileInfo.Name())`) and then only change the fields that doesn't fill in for you or that you want to override.

Comment: I think that helps but I'm still having issues *sigh*.  Apparently it's not walking hidden directories also.